# Adding custom directories (source and spec) to autotest in a Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest, rspec2

I have a Rails 3 app that uses RSpec2 as my testing framework, and I'm able to use autotest to watch my model and spec directories for changes and re-run my spec suite when files change.

I'd like to add a directory with some custom classes in it (RAILS_ROOT/lib/some_project/lib/*.rb) and their corresponding specs (RAILS_ROOT/spec/some_project/*_spec.rb) so that autotest will automatically pick up changes to all of those files and re-run as needed.

How do I get autotest to watch these files in these other directories?  I suspect I have to add something to RAILS_ROOT/autotest/discover.rb, but I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you want to do:
http://seandenigris.com/blog/?p=337

Comment: Cool thanks! I'd since given up and consolidated my custom directories into the main test directory but this does look like what I was trying to achieve...