# Tell autotest to run when view file is modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest

How do I change the behavior of `autotest` to run after I edit a view file?  Currently, it runs when I modify a a controller file, and I'd rather not need to `touch` a a controller file to get my tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thread: [Adding custom directories (source and spec) to autotest in a Rails 3 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605267/adding-custom-directories-source-and-spec-to-autotest-in-a-rails-3-project)

Infinity test has pretty good customization support too: https://github.com/tomas-stefano/infinity_test